# Insert rows in a table, via a row-level trigger, activated after insertion in that same table

Tags: mysql, trigger, schema

I have to design a schema and trigger system in SQL that will save **words** and their **synonyms**.

I thought of this basic schema:

```
create table words (
    id int primary key auto_increment,
    word varchar(50)
);

create table synonyms(
    w1 int references words(id),
    w2 int references words(id),
    primary key (w1, w2)
);
```

Another requirement is to make the synonyms relation *symmetric* (if a is a synonym of b, then b is a synonym of a and the table synonyms should be updated accordingly).

I thought of using a trigger that looks like this:

```
create trigger MakeSynonymsSymmetric
after insert on synonyms
for each row
insert into synonyms
values (new.w2, new.w1);
```

Which of course won't work because the trigger activates itself generating an infinite loop (or at least that's my understanding).

Trying to insert into `synonyms` gives me this error:

> Can't update table 'synonyms' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

Any way around this problem by defining the schema in a different way, but always using triggers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To perform what you are looking for based on this example:

```
INSERT INTO synonym_bucket VALUES (23,37);
```

## SUGGESTION #1

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS synonym_bucket;
CREATE TABLE synonym_bucket LIKE synonyms;
ALTER TABLE synonym_bucket ENGINE=BLACKHOLE;
DELIMITER $$   
CREATE TRIGGER MakeTwoSynonyms
AFTER INSERT ON synonym_bucket 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF new.w1 <> new.w2 THEN
        INSERT IGNORE INTO synonyms VALUES (new.w1, new.w2),(new.w2, new.w1);
    END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Using `synonym_bucket` takes up just 2K (table definition plus trigger)

**Bottom Line**: For a table's before and after trigger, you cannot perform additional DML to the same table. However, you can do DML from a trigger to another table. This is why I made a [**BLACKHOLE**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/blackhole-storage-engine.html) table. It takes up to 2K (table definition and the trigger code). You use it to write to a separate table. In this case, `synonym_bucket` does the double INSERT into `synonyms`.

## SUGGESTION #2

Do the the double INSERT yourself

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO synonyms VALUES (23,37),(37,23);
```

No trigger required

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Comment: First of all, thank you. The solution seems to work, however I hoped in a somehow "cleaner" solution and don't really understand the necessity of setting ENGINE=BLACKHOLE

Comment: I updated the `synonym_backet` table's trigger and added an explanation.